# Calculate Section (area) of N-Dimensional Tube

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, area

I have the following n-dimensional shape
$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}^{2}$ where $a_{i}>0$ and I'd like to calculate the cross-section area inside. Any suggestion?

Note: I call it an $n$-dimensional tube because I actually have $1=\sum_{i=2}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}^{2}$ and $x_{1}$ can have any value, but I only care of $x_{1}=constant$ in my problem.

Comment: are you describing hyper-ellipsoids? In 3D, $a_1 x^2 + a_2 y^2 + a_3 z^2 =1$. If so, wouldn't the cross-section be an ellipse?

Comment: Yess, that's true for $n=3$, I don't really know how to go to the $n$-dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For purposes of your question, it's more convenient to write the ellipsoid in terms of the semi-axes, $b_{i} = 1/\sqrt{a_{i}}$:
$$
1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{b_{i}^{2}}.
$$
The $n$-dmensional volume is the product of the semi-axes and the [volume of the unit $n$-dimensional ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball):
$$
\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} b_{i}
  = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{i}}}.
$$
To see this, apply the change of variables theorem to the linear scaling
$$
(u_{1}, \dots, u_{n}) \mapsto (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = (b_{1} u_{1}, \dots, b_{n} u_{n}),
$$
observing that the unit $n$-ball maps to the ellipsoid.